# Converting Pine Script into MQL4 language (Easy Indicator)

Tags: pine-script, mql4

This is a High/Low indicator in Pine Script language. Can anyone help me to convert it into MQL4. It should be very easy for some of you ;)

```
lenH = input(title="Length High", type=input.integer, defval=5, minval=1)
lenL = input(title="Length Low", type=input.integer, defval=5, minval=1)

fun(src, len, isHigh, _style, _yloc, _color) =>

p = nz(src[len])
isFound = true
for i = 0 to len - 1
    if isHigh and src[i] > p
        isFound := false
    if not isHigh and src[i] < p
        isFound := false
for i = len + 1 to 2 * len
    if isHigh and src[i] >= p
        isFound := false
    if not isHigh and src[i] <= p
        isFound := false
if isFound
    label.new(bar_index[len], p, tostring(p), style=_style, yloc=_yloc, color=_color)
fun(close, lenH, true, label.style_labeldown, yloc.abovebar, color.lime)
fun(close, lenL, false, label.style_labelup, yloc.belowbar, color.red)
```

The result should be like this in 1hr timeframe.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrQDp.png)

Comment: SO is not that kind of web resource.

Answer (score 0):

oh, I have found the answer la.

```
  #include <stdlib.mqh>
  #include <stderror.mqh>
  
  //--- indicator settings
  #property indicator_chart_window
  #property indicator_buffers 2
  
  #property indicator_type1 DRAW_ARROW
  #property indicator_width1 1
  #property indicator_color1 0x4800FF
  #property indicator_label1 "HIGH"
  
  #property indicator_type2 DRAW_ARROW
  #property indicator_width2 1
  #property indicator_color2 0x2FFF00
  #property indicator_label2 "LOW"
  
  //--- indicator buffers
  double Buffer1[];
  double Buffer2[];
  
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  
  double myPoint; //initialized in OnInit
  
  void myAlert(string type, string message)
    {
     if(type == "print")
        Print(message);
     else if(type == "error")
       {
        Print(type+" | Pivot Point @ "+Symbol()+","+IntegerToString(Period())+" | "+message);
       }
     else if(type == "order")
       {
       }
     else if(type == "modify")
       {
       }
    }
  
  //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
  //| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
  //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
  int OnInit()
    {   
     IndicatorBuffers(2);
     SetIndexBuffer(0, Buffer1);
     SetIndexEmptyValue(0, EMPTY_VALUE);
     SetIndexArrow(0, 67);
     SetIndexBuffer(1, Buffer2);
     SetIndexEmptyValue(1, EMPTY_VALUE);
     SetIndexArrow(1, 67);
     //initialize myPoint
     myPoint = Point();
     if(Digits() == 5 || Digits() == 3)
       {
        myPoint *= 10;
       }
     return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
    }
  
  //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
  //| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
  //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
  int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                  const int prev_calculated,
                  const datetime& time[],
                  const double& open[],
                  const double& high[],
                  const double& low[],
                  const double& close[],
                  const long& tick_volume[],
                  const long& volume[],
                  const int& spread[])
    {
   
    
     
     //--- main loop
     int HighCandle = iHighest(NULL,0,MODE_CLOSE,11,1);
     int LowCandle = iLowest(NULL,0,MODE_CLOSE,11,1);
     if(HighCandle == 6)
        {
           Buffer1[6] = Close[6];
        }else if(LowCandle == 6)
           {
             Buffer2[6] = Close[6];
           }
        
     return(rates_total);
    }
  //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Enjoy d:)

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I'm a beginner at MQL4. When I copy-and-paste your code into a new indicator file, the file compiles correctly, but nothing shows on screen when I attach it to the terminal.